# Jquery MultiSelect - Change font-size and width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to change the font-size and the width of a Jquery multiselet dropdown but I can't find how. I am using this http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget widget and my dropdown looks great and even have the theme I choosed for the rest of the page but the font-size is way to big. I tried changing it in the jquery.multiselect.css (loaded after other jquery css) and I tried adding

```
.ui-multiselect{
font-size: 12px;
width: 200px;}
```

in a css loaded after every other css with no luck.

I must be doing something wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you check out that select in your browser element inspector, what CSS selector actually gets the final say on `font-size`?

Answer (score 1):

In your css, use
`.ms-options-wrap > .ms-options > ul li label{
    font-size:your-sizepx;
}`

This will override the default css

Answer (score 0):

Go for something more direct that overrides the existing font-size setting. In the case of the demo here :: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic

You will find that the font-size style is applied at the level of

.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li { }

Your best bet to check for this in your case is to open the selector, hover over one of the options and then 'view element' and study the css styles being applied, finding exactly which style it is that the text inherits from.

[image]

If you continue to have problems, create a plunket/jsfiddle demo and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

in your css use this code

```
.ms-options-wrap > button:focus,
.ms-options-wrap > button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    **font-size: 11px;**
    color: #aaa;
    outline-offset: -2px;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
```

if it's still not working use !important
Example => font-size:11px !important;